# Apply Gaussian Blur Filter only in Touched areas in xCode

Tags: ios, xcode5

Here is Gaussian Filter for all image

```
//Get a UIImage from the UIView
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Blur the UIImage
CIImage *imageToBlur = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:viewImage.CGImage];
CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[gaussianBlurFilter setValue:imageToBlur forKey:@"inputImage"];
[gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
CIImage *resultImage = [gaussianBlurFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
UIImage *endImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:resultImage];

//Place the UIImage in a UIImageView
newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
newView.image = endImage;
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

I was searching for clases that will apply Blur Filter only for touches area in image but founded only this filter for whole image. My question is about how to make CIFilter be applied only for:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ ... }
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ ... }
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ ... }
```

Comment: Maybe you can write the code in those methods ?

Comment: Well if am asking if this is possible. Couldn't figure out yet what to write there.

Answer (score 0):

Juste like this it should work :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
    //Get a UIImage from the UIView
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Blur the UIImage
    CIImage *imageToBlur = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:viewImage.CGImage];
    CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:imageToBlur forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
    CIImage *resultImage = [gaussianBlurFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    UIImage *endImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:resultImage];

    //Place the UIImage in a UIImageView
    newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    newView.image = endImage;
    [self.view addSubview:newView]; 
}
```

And the same for the other methods :)

Comment: No, here you just add whole image blurred to default image.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, you want to detect the area pressed and just apply the blur to this area ?

Comment: Yes that's what i am looking for. A blur tool similar to Photoshop.

Comment: This should help you I guess : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558993/iphone-touch-area-detection